# Most Efficient Data Type for Fixed Length Column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sqldatatypes, mysql-5.6

I'm just in the process of designing my database structures.

There are a number of columns that are fixed length, at least one of which is purely alphanumeric.

Hence I'm wondering:

1. What is (or are) the most efficient data type(s) for fixed length columns in general?
2. What is (or are) the most efficient data type(s) for fixed length alphanumeric columns?
3. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  As tadman says: 'Use VARCHAR and don't worry about it'

Long answer:

The space consumed by the column is the main factor for both space and speed.

Truly fixed-length strings can be declared `CHAR(..)`.  Very often, they are composed only of ascii characters, so the 'right' way to do it is, for example

```
country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii
uuid CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

The difference between a fixed length `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR` is the 1- or 2-byte length field preceding the actual string.  Unless you have billions of rows, this is 'not a big deal'.

The processing speed difference is insignificant, but `CHAR` and `ascii` win.

If you have all-numeric strings, you *may* want to use `INT` 4 bytes or `BIGINT` 8 bytes or `DECIMAL(30)` 14 bytes, etc -- instead of using `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, which will have 1 byte per digit.  The numeric fields are all fixed length.  But, be careful.  US phone numbers are fixed length, but international numbers vary.

You imply that there is something other than "alphanumeric".  If you are referring to `BINARY`/`VARBINARY`/`BLOB`, then the rules are mostly the same.

For example, a uuid can be shrunk from `CHAR(36)` (36 bytes) to `BINARY(16)` (16 bytes) via a suitable transformation.  There latter is better for speed and space, but it adds complexity to your code.  (Anyway, uuids are terrible for huge table; this is another topic.)

With integers, always consider `BIGINT` vs `INT` vs `MEDIUMINT` vs `SMALLINT` vs `TINYINT`, and usually tack on `UNSIGNED`.  (Those take 8/4/3/2/1 bytes, respectively.)  Do it when you originally create the table; it is messy to do an `ALTER` later.

Answer (score 1):

Use `VARCHAR` and don't worry about it.

This is only a concern when you're handling so much data it won't fit on a single drive, or even then, a single server jammed full of drives.

Companies that manage databases with multiple billions of rows have problems with this, but you won't until you're that big.

Comment: include some info about `char` for fixed length and ill mark this as the answer

Comment: you still hold the same position even if a row has as many as 27 columns?

Comment: You're going to get way more in the way of performance gains by coming up with a more optimal schema or using something like a `JSON` type column instead of some excessively wide row, but in any case MySQL usually doesn't care or suffer.

Comment: If you ever have questions about performance like this, write a script to test your system by inserting *N* million rows and see how it holds up. Your provider's performance characteristics are entirely unique.

Comment: is there even a `JSON` data type?! thanks for the tip!

Comment: MySQL 5.7 has support, so it's worth checking out.